# Peripheral state never changes after CBPeripheralStateDisconnecting state on mac osx 10.13 CoreBluetooth framework

Tags: objective-c, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, xcode9.2

I have updated macOS to High sierra and Xcode to 9.2. I am working on BLE device connection / disconnection and reading data. It was was working fine in Xcode 8.2, Now there are changes in  CoreBluetooth framework.

A new state `CBPeripheralStateDisconnecting` is added in peripheral state. Now, I need functionality to cancel connection with BLE device from `CBPeripheralStateConnecting` state, too.

I have used `cancelPeripheralConnection:` method to cancel connection. After this method device state changes to `CBPeripheralStateDisconnecting` and never gets into state `CBPeripheralStateDisconnected`. I tried to connect again but still state not changing.

In short BLE device state never changes after `CBPeripheralStateDisconnecting` state. Please can anyone suggest a way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody gone through same issue yet?I am still searching for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved issue by treating CBPeripheralStateDisconnecting & CBPeripheralStateDisconnected state as same. Implemented same flow on CBPeripheralStateDisconnecting as CBPeripheralStateDisconnected i.e. send connection request again to device & it worked.